# How to correctly handle escape squences in file input

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, unicode-escapes

I'm building a program that reads some input from the user. If this input contains an escape character, for example, '\n', then I need to handle it like a newline, not like the literal string `r'\n'`. This has to work for **every possible** escape sequence, not just common ones like \r, \n, etc.. I've tried using `shlex` and `ast` to achieve this behavior, but I receive an error.

My Code:

```py
import shlex
import ast
text = r"result:"
escaped_text = ast.literal_eval(shlex.quote(text))
print(escaped_text)
```

Error:

```
...
File "<unknown>", line 1
    \x1b[31mError:
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Comment: Maybe `+ r"\x1b[0m"` (note the second `r"`)?

Comment: Can't repro - working for me.

Comment: For some reason, this example works now to... Weird

Comment: Yeah, still can't reproduce the error. But glad it's working for you now :)

Comment: @alani Edited again... The issue only seems to happen when the text is `"result:"`. I dunno why..

Comment: I had placed a "close" vote on the grounds of not reproducible. I have now retracted this because I can now reproduce *an* error, but please can you edit the question again so that the error message is exactly the same as you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`shlex.quote` might not be the tool for the job here, because it sometimes produces outer quotes and sometimes doesn't:

```
>>> print(shlex.quote("a"))
a
>>> print(shlex.quote("a\n"))
'a
'
```

`literal_eval` is going to require outer quotes to be there in order to allow string expressions to be treated as such. (Your error is with an input string that does not get outer quotes added by `shlex.quote`.)

Basically you want something like:

```
escaped_text = ast.literal_eval(f"'{text}'")
```

but there is a problem if `text` itself contains `'` symbols.  Just in order to deal with this corner case, unfortunately you would need to do something like:

```
text2 = text.replace("'","'"'"'"'"'"'"'")
```

so that a single `'` is replaced by `'"'"'` -- and the even longer `"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"` here is the source code required to represent the (5-character) string shown.

You can then do:

```
escaped_text = ast.literal_eval(f"'{text2}'")
```